# Combining two Google App Engine datastore results?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to combine two Google App Engine datastore results.  Because I then want to list them together in the template.

For example:
other_user_answers = UserAnswer.gql("WHERE user = :1", user.key()).fetch(500)
my_answers = UserAnswer.gql("WHERE user = :1", me.key()).fetch(500)

I want to combine these results based on question.key().id().  So that I can do something like this in the template:

```
{% for other_user_answer in other_user_answers %}
    Question #{{other_user_answer.question.key.id}}<br>
    User: {{other_user_answer.answer}}
    Me:  {{other_user_answer.my_answer}}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm not sure if I'm explaining it the best way or not!  But something along those lines.

Also, I'm not quite sure what the Google App Engine datastore results come back in (like list, dict, etc), so I'm not quite sure what I'm even working with.

EDIT for more explanation:
Users are going to answer a bunch of questions.  Then when I'm logged into the site and go to a different user's page (Jimmy).  I want to list all of Jimmy's answers with all of my answers next to his as well.  So I pull from the table UserAnswer and get all the answers for me.... and then for Jimmy.  So now I have two sets of results.  I want to spit them out as one though based on the Question ID.

Like:

Favorite color?
Me: red
Jimmy: blue

Favorite Ice cream?
Me: Chocolate
Jimmy: Vanilla

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'combine'? Will every instance of `other_user_question` contain `my_answer` and what's `my_questions` doing?

Comment: I updated it to try to explain it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is probably to turn the list returned by one of the fetch() operations into a dict keyed by question id.  Then you walk over the other list and pull the value out of the dict based on the question id, making sure to deal with missing entries (e.g. questions Jimmy answered but you didn't), and store those on an extra attribute (e.g. my_answer).  After that you can pass that list to the template.

Answer (score 0):

`Gql(...).fetch(...)` returns you a list of entities. I am not quite sure if they way you are working with is correct, unless you put up the structure of Question and explain a bit more.

BTW, it would be better if you could HTML-escape the content you are sending to the browser, unless of course you are very sure about the content. You could use `autoescape` tag, or something like `{{my_variable|escape}}`

Comment: I think I have it setup so that everything is escaped automatically.